# c# : how to remove tabcontrol border?

Tags: c#, forms

In my form, I'm using a tabcontrol. I want to hide the tab headers and border both. I can do either one, if I try to hide the headers then the border becomes visible. Can anyone help me, please? thanks and here's my code:

```
public Form3()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.NativeTabControl1 = new NativeTabControl();

    this.NativeTabControl1.AssignHandle(this.tabControl1.Handle);

}

private NativeTabControl NativeTabControl1;

private class NativeTabControl : NativeWindow
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if ((m.Msg == TCM_ADJUSTRECT))
        {
            RECT rc = (RECT)m.GetLParam(typeof(RECT));
            //Adjust these values to suit, dependant upon Appearance
            rc.Left -= 3;
            rc.Right += 3;
            rc.Top -= 3;
            rc.Bottom += 3;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, m.LParam, true);
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private const Int32 TCM_FIRST = 0x1300;
    private const Int32 TCM_ADJUSTRECT = (TCM_FIRST + 40);
    private struct RECT
    {
        public Int32 Left;
        public Int32 Top;
        public Int32 Right;
        public Int32 Bottom;
    }

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //hides tabcontrol headers
        tabControl1.Appearance = TabAppearance.Buttons;
        tabControl1.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
        tabControl1.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is [another thread on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953487/remove-hide-tab-headerswitcher-of-c-sharp-tabcontrol), which provides some ideas to hide the tab row of the `TabControl` in Windows Forms.
My favorite one is to override `WndProc` and set the `Multiline` property to `true`.

```
public partial class TabControlWithoutHeader : TabControl
{
    public TabControlWithoutHeader()
    {
        if (!this.DesignMode) this.Multiline = true;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x1328 && !this.DesignMode)
            m.Result = new IntPtr(1);
        else
            base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

I tested the code on Windows 8.1 and see neither the tabs nor a border line. So I think you do not need to use code like you posted.

Comment: Works on Windows 7. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I would usually suggest doing this in the xaml not C# (I'm a WPF developer) I believe you can do it in the C# as well by naming both the TabControl as well as each Tab itself.

```
tabControlName.BorderBrush = null;
///^Gets rid of the TabControl's border.

tabName1.Height = 0;
tabName2.Height = 0;
tabNameETC.Height = 0;
///^Removes the tabs(headers) if you have the TabControl.TabStripPlacement set to left 
/// or right, then use the following instead:

tabName1.Width = 0
tabName2.Width = 0
tabNameETC.Width = 0
```

Comment: When I tried to apply got the following error on TabControl after the execution of the first line of the code. ('System.Windows.Forms.TabControl' does not contain a definition for 'BorderBrush')

Comment: `BorderBrush` is not a defined property for type `TabControl`