# Remove Tabs Layout in TabControl - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, layout, hide, tabcontrol

I want To hide Tabs Layout (that are at the top of TabControl) when the Application is running.
But i need them to be visible when i am designing the form. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

From Hans Passant at [Hide Tab Header on C# TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953487/remove-hide-tab-headerswitcher-of-c-sharp-tabcontrol)

Direct link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6954785/3055288

```
Public Class TablessControl
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        ' Hide tabs by trapping the TCM_ADJUSTRECT message
        If (m.Msg = &H1328 And Not DesignMode) Then
            m.Result = CType(1, IntPtr)
        Else
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I translated his code to VB.NET and I'm using it myself. It works very nicely.

Comment: The vb.net equivalent of C# hex suffix `0x` is `&H`. So you can replace `Convert.ToInt32("0x1328", 16)` with `&H1328`.

Comment: That's true. I will change this. The cast is definitely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, and I know ones already been accepted, but this is how I do it

```
With TabControl1
    .Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons
    .ItemSize = New Size(0, 1)
    .SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed
End With
```