# Access a ListView located in a UserControl from the MainForm in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have an app that uses a side menu, and for each button (there are 3) on the left side menu, it changes the pages shown.

I tried doing it with multiple panels, but it's a nightmare to maintain in designer, and it's probably not a very good programming habit, I expect.

So I search and found what seemed to be a great idea: `UserControl`.
But as usual, it's not that simple (for a badly self-taught guy like me)

The general flow of the program is as follows:

- a Btn_uc1_Check button that gathers informations and displays them in a uc1_ListView,
- a Btn_uc2_Seek button that gathers informations on the net based on the uc1_ListView , and displays them on uc2_ListView,
- a Btn_uc3_compile that compiles the info from uc2_ListView into a file,
- a Clear button that clears the ListView depending on the UserControl on screen.

Now to the problem:

- How on earth do I gain access to a ListView located in a UserControl to be able to read, clear, and add items from the MainFrom or from another UserControl?

I searched and honestly found nothing corresponding to what I needed?

Comment: Sounds like it is all a big ball of wax.  Adding structure to a program has to be done up front.  Beyond scratching v0.1 as a learning exercise, do consider the quick fix.  What you need as a tab control, behaves very well in the designer, but without the tabs.  [That is easy to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6954785/17034).

Answer (score 0):

Quite many questions.

1. You can gain access to any controls in UC. Just change the property "Modifiers" of the ListView in your UC to "Public".

[image: Example1]

2. Set that method to public. Do not use keyword "static". Each control
   in your form is an instance of a class, not a static class actually. In the main form, create a button and double click on it in VS designer. A method will automatically generated, something like *private void button1_Click*. When the button is clicked, all of the code lines in button1_Click will run.
3. Create a public event handler of your user control, then pass the method in main to the handler.

So the UC class will be similar to this:

```
public event EventHandler button_UC_Click_handler;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_UC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button_UC_Click_handler.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
```

In main form:

```
public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        userControl11.button_UC_Click_handler += UserControl11_button_UC_Click_handler;
    }

    private void UserControl11_button_UC_Click_handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have clicked it!");
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: 1. I tried setting the modifiers to public, but still no sugar.
2. As for the rest, three button is on the main form, so I tried as you've shown and I tried the other way around, but still a no go.

But thanks anyway for trying to help :)