# Tabcontrol and Text Placement using VB.net Form

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I am trying to build out an application that has tabs on the left, but I want the text to be horizontal and not vertical. I have seen many forum posts for WPF and C#, but nothing specific to VB.net.

Is there a specific property I can use to have the text change from vertical to horizontal? How do I implement this type of change? I know this seems novice like to be asking, but I feel I have hit a brick wall. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just emulate it with Label controls.  You can still use TabPages by [hiding the tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6954785/17034).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the following on the .Net Resource page for Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-display-side-aligned-tabs-with-tabcontrol

The only item I now want to be able to do is add in padding to the text so that its not right against the dialog box. If anyone has any ideas, please advise.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.DrawItem
Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
Dim _TextBrush As Brush

' Get the item from the collection.
Dim _TabPage As TabPage = TabControl1.TabPages(e.Index)

' Get the real bounds for the tab rectangle.
Dim _TabBounds As Rectangle = TabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index)

If (e.State = DrawItemState.Selected) Then
    ' Draw a different background color, and don't paint a focus rectangle.
    _TextBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.Red)
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds)
Else
    _TextBrush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
    e.DrawBackground()
End If

' Use our own font.
Dim _TabFont As New Font("Arial", 10.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

' Draw string. Center the text.
Dim _StringFlags As New StringFormat()
_StringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
_StringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
g.DrawString(_TabPage.Text, _TabFont, _TextBrush, _TabBounds, New StringFormat(_StringFlags))
End Sub
```